# javascript- site cookies are not deleted

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am saving and restoring cookies using JavaScript in my website and I encountered an issue where I cannot delete those cookies.
I tries deleting then in code and also by clearing chrome history (from the beginning of time). I have red written posts and tried all sort of things but nothing fixed it for me.

here's my code that handles the cookies:

```
var createCookie = function (name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

after deleting chorme history, I execute this line of code :

```
var cookieHdrStr = getCookie("cart_header");
```

and I expect`cookieHdrStr` to be null/undefined but instead it restores the last cookie I saved.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong...
It turns out I had a line of code I wasn't aware of:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { saveDocumentCookie(); }
```

whenever unloading the page it was saving the cookies, so even when I deleted them and pressed f5 to refresh the page, before refreshing it was saving cookies.